# On a bus or on the bus?

Tags: articles

Today, I was talking to my friend. She is very good at English. During this conversation, she said, "I am on THE bus". I think, she has misused the definite article. In my opinion, it should have been, "I am on A bus". Because this is the first time she said anything about this bus. On the other hand, I know that she generally travel by bus.

Comment: Where I live (north of UK), it's common to say "I'm on 't bus'.  Where 't is a contraction of "the".  This could be pronounced (Yorkshire folk pronounce 't as "tuh"), but some would even miss that out and put a stopping sound on "on" to almost make it "on'd" as in "I'm on'd bus". (Oh, and in Oldham bus is pronounced buzz).

Comment: You don't tell us whether you were _also_ on the bus, or whether this was a phone conversation. That information is important here.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - This was a phone conversation.

Comment: Our use of the definite article is extremely nuanced and complex. When I proof-read my friend's writing (a fluent, but non-native, speaker), I invariably remove every 'the' they include, and insert every one they omit - to their eternal frustration.

Comment: According to what I have understood, “I am on the bus” is ONLY ACCEPTED because it is a fixed expression just like “I am on the phone”, right? Suppose my friend were on her motorbike, then it would have been wrong for her to say, “I am on the motorbike”. Did I get it correct?

Answer (score 31):

You wouldn't normally say *on a bus*; *on the bus* is a fixed expression.

The reason why *the* is used in that phrase is probably because *the bus* here is something we all know about, something that by extension refers to the institution that represents the (public) transport bus service that uses buses to drive people around the city. The phrase doesn't refer to any bus in particular per se.

In his book, *Practical English Usage* (69.5), M. Swan says the following:

> We use *the* (with a singular countable noun) when we talk about some kinds of thing that are part of everybody's lives, like ‘the bus’ or ‘the hairdresser’. In this case *the bus*, for example, does not mean ‘one bus that you know about’; we use *the* to suggest that taking a bus is a common experience that we all share.

---

To address the comment and some additional questions one might have after reading the above:

I merely wanted to answer the question of whether *on the bus* is grammatical in that context, and how that's accomplished – not suggest that *on a bus* isn't. It would be more usual, given the context the asker provided, for their friend to say *I'm on the bus* and not *I'm on a bus*.

*I'm on the bus* might mean "I'm on the bus I tell you I'm on every day – my school bus", i.e., "...the bus you expect me to be on at this time". It could also mean "I'm on the bus we previously discussed". Et cetera.

Can you say *on a bus*? Yes, you can say, for example,

> I can't talk to you right now, I'm on a bus.

As you said, this introduces a bus; you're talking about it for the first time and identifying the vehicle as a bus.

> Last week he was on a bus when an argument erupted between... ([independent.co.uk](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/the-maltese-dream-thats-more-a-migrants-nightmare-8756427.html)).

He was on a bus – it doesn't matter what bus. The same applies in the example that follows:

> "It doesn't. Why would it? I'm nobody." She lowered her chin as her face twisted up. "Just a girl you met on a bus." (*Don't Move* by Dennis Etchison)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with saying "on a bus", though "on the bus" is certainly more common, especially if it is a bus you take regularly.

Comment: I'll add that it's perfectly acceptable to ask a question like "Which bus?" in order to know what bus the person is specifically on.

Comment: It's funny that in M.Swan's quote, taking **a** bus is actually used towards the end. Ironic, or what?

Comment: @userr2684291 Your explanation makes sense, I think it really is what most users of English feel when they reflect on and interpret their use of such fixed expressions. I want to add that this general use of a definite article is not restricted to English. In German and in my second language Luxembourgish, we use/imply the same definite article when we refer to these common experiences! The same holds for phrases like "the butcher's", "the doctor", etc. We even use it for "school", where English has not even an article.

Comment: @AshwinSchumann For what it's worth, there are situations that call for using the definite article w/ "school". A kid is "at school" but, after the fight breaks out, his father will explain to the missus that he's "at the school" talking to the teachers; the first is actually describing an activity or state, the latter the location.

Comment: @userr2684291 - According to what I have understood, “I am on the bus” is ONLY ACCEPTED because it is a fixed expression just like “I am on the phone”, right? Suppose my friend were on her motorbike, then it would have been wrong for her to say, “I am on the motorbike”. Did I get it correct?

Comment: @AhmbroDude No. It's a fixed expression BECAUSE *the bus* we're talking about is what we both (and everyone generally) know about. No, you didn't get it. A similar expression would be *I'm on the train*, however. *Motorbike*, *car*, etc. aren't the same as *train* and *bus*. This usage now boils down to the ordinary usage of articles. You can say *the motorbike/car* if you expect the listener/reader to know which one. Maybe you could say *I'm in the car*, and the listener would infer that it's your car they're talking about.

Answer (score 22):

Both are equally acceptable.  "On *the* bus" is usually used in situations where the bus is something the person commonly uses.  "On *a* bus" is used more for one-off type situations.

Examples:

> Why are you so grumpy this morning? Some idiot on the bus kept
>   bothering me.
>
> My parents met on a bus to New York City.

Again, these are not strict rules. Just how they seemed to be used.

Answer (score 16):

Both are correct but express subtle differences.

> I'm on the bus.  I'll be there in 20 minutes.

Expresses that you are on a specific bus that is meaningful to the conversation.  In this case, the assumption is the listener is likely aware of which bus or route you're on so the 20 minute expectation is reasonable.

> I'm on a bus.  The cell service is really bad.

Expresses that while you are on a bus, it doesn't matter which bus or route, just that your on a bus and that is why you cell service is poor.

Comment: This is my favorite answer.  The article "the" specifying a precise or known context and the article "a" obfuscating the issue.  Maybe it's because I grew up in a family full of lawyers!  "On the bus" implies the listener knows which bus the speaker is on.  "On a bus" implies the listener might not know and the speaker doesn't want to reveal it.

Answer (score 0):

If your friend was speaking about how she was travelling at that particular moment in time, then generally in the North of England, 'on the bus' is what one would say.  On *a* bus is not incorrect, because your friend is certainly on *a* bus, but it is not the usual way to say that one is travelling by bus.

If your friend was not sure that she was on the correct bus for her journey then 'on *a* bus' would be more appropriate.  She is on *a* bus but it might not be definitely *the* bus that will get her to where she wants to be.

Answer (score -1):

You could have asked her, "What do you mean you're on the bus? Which one are you on?" And she would have said something like, "Well I'm on the 29 of course, the one I always take to get home."

The definitive article is indeed the one to use here. It's not just any old bus, even though it might actually be a different vehicle, it is one that follows the route she takes every day.